# Comparing two integers to check if the second integer is greater

Tags: java, validation, int

I am trying to have the user input two integers where the second integer must be greater. This is to be complete with validation. Validation seems to work but when the second integer is input regardless if the the int is smaller or has been corrected, the first input is printed.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Comparing
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);



 //Entering Integers where int 2 is greater with validation

       int i1;
       while(true){
         System.out.print("Enter the first integer");
        if(in.hasNextInt()){
          i1 = in.nextInt();
          break;
        }else{
          System.out.println("Invalid Integer");
          String Invalid = in.next(); //Meant to catch any non int types
        }
      }
      int i2;
      while(true){
         System.out.print("Enter a second larger integer");
       if(in.hasNextBigInteger()){
         i2 = in.nextInt();          
        if(i2 > i1){
          break;
        }else{
           System.out.println("Invalid Integer");
           System.out.println("Enter a second LARGER integer");
           String Invalid2 = in.next();

        }
        break;
        }else{
          System.out.println("Invalid Integer");
          System.out.println("Enter a second LARGER integer");
          String Invalid2 = in.next();  
        }    
      }  



//Odd number calculation between i1 and i2
   int oddsum = 0;
   int odd = 0;
   for(odd = i1;odd <= i2; odd++){
     if(odd%2 != 0){
       oddsum = odd + oddsum;
     }
   }
   System.out.println("The sum of odd integers between " + i1 + " and " + i2 + ": " + oddsum);
```

Comment: Your code seems to work fine. What input did you use to make it not work? What did it output? What did you expect it to output?

Comment: I forgot to add the print, The calculation to go with it. If you were to enter int1 as 6 and then int2 as 3, it will prompt correction, you enter 9 and breaks. But the number recorded is the 3

Comment: sorry, i edited it and it should have the calculation in it to show you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should delete these two lines:

```
int i2;
while(true){
    System.out.print("Enter a second larger integer");
    if(in.hasNextBigInteger()){
        i2 = in.nextInt();
        if(i2 > i1){
            break;
        }else{
            System.out.println("Invalid Integer");
            System.out.println("Enter a second LARGER integer");
            String Invalid = in.next(); // <----- this line
        }
        break; // <------------ and this line
    }else{
        System.out.println("Invalid Integer");
        System.out.println("Enter a second LARGER integer");
        String Invalid2 = in.next();
    }
}
```

You don't need to do `in.next` consume the invalid integer because `nextInt` *will* consume it (unlike in the integer in the wrong format case)!

You also don't break out of the loop. You want the loop to loop again to make the user enter a correct number.

You don't need the `String Invalid` declarations either. Just doing `in.next();` is enough.

Comment: Thank you, it seemed to have problems earlier without those lines but maybe i confused myself.